# Given an executable produced by MSVC, is there a way to tell if exceptions were enabled?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Given a "Hello world" program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

And a CMake script that generates the projects (the commented line will produce an executable without exceptions enabled):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_compile_options(main PRIVATE "/EHsc")
# target_compile_options(main PRIVATE "/EHs-")
```

Is there a way to tell which executable produced has exceptions enabled or not (with specifically executables produced with MSVC 2015?). I notice the running `dumpbin /imports` on both, they both import `RaiseException` from `KERNEL32.dll` (in fact, their imports are identical).

Comment: Well, yeah, there is a way to tell. Analyze the disassembly to see if it ever throws an exception. Is that workable? What are you *actually* trying to do? In what context do you need to make this determination?

Comment: Using any offline tools to make the determination would be sufficient, although, I'd like to be able to use it in an automated process, so any required intervention by the user would be undesirable.

Comment: If you're building these things, why don't you just add a custom signature that you can detect? For example, you could conditionally add "Comments" or some other string data to the `VERSIONINFO` resource. This can then be extracted and read easily, either by the application itself or by an external tool with read access to the binary.

Comment: I would like it to work on executables I haven't built, the example I used was just for illustration.